# Swift - Locksmith loadDataForUserAccount fails sometimes?

Tags: ios, swift, keychain

I have a strange bug that is occurring only on few user iPhones, details below -

The app consumes a universal framework (developed by ourself) to save accessToken and refreshToken after successful login to the Keychain. We are using [Locksmith](https://github.com/matthewpalmer/Locksmith) to achieve the functionality - Save, load data and delete when the user is logged out.

Everytime when the app is killed and launched or `applicationWillEnterForeground`, the tokens are refreshed with the help of a service call and are saved to keychain again. When the `refreshToken` expires (this token is valid for one month), user is notified that the app has not been used for a long time and he is logged out.

The actual problem is here that for only few users, the refresh mechanism fails even when they are using the app daily (i.e. not before completion of one month of the `refreshToken`). After verification with backend team, the `refresh` service is always up so I suspect the Locksmith `loadDataForUserAccount` but unable to reproduce the issue. Also, may users do NOT face the problem. Everything works normally as expected.

Can someone help me move further how to identify the cause?

Below is the code to refresh the `accessToken` and `refreshToken`

** Refresh token call From the App when app enters foreground or killed and launched**

```
if let mySession = ServiceLayer.sharedInstance.session {

            mySession.refresh {  result in

                switch result {
                case .failure(.authenticationFailure):

                    if isBackgroundFetch {
                        print("⚠️ Session refresh failed, user is now logged out.")
                        self.myService.logoutCurrentUser()

                        // Logout Current user
                        mySession.invalidate()

                        self.showLoginUI()
                    }
                    else {
                        // user accessToken is invalid but provide access to QR
                        // on the home screen. disable all other actions except logout button

                        self.showHomeScreen()
                    }

                default:
                    mySession.getAccessToken { result in
                        switch result {

                        case let .success(value):
                            print("Access Token from App Delegate \(value)")
                            myAccessToken = value


                        case let .failure(error):
                            print("❌ Failed to fetch AccessToken: \(error)")                            

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

**From the framework where the refresh mechanism is implemented**

```
public func refresh(_ completion: @escaping (MyResult<String, MyError>) -> (Void)) {

        guard isValid else {
            completion(.failure(.invalidSession))
            return
        }

        getRefreshToken { result in

            switch result {
            case let .success(refreshToken):

                // Get new tokens.
                ServiceClient.requestJSON(ServiceRequest.refreshToken(refreshToken: refreshToken)) { result in

                    switch result {
                    case let .success(dictionary):
                        var newAccessToken: String?
                        var newRefreshToken: String?

                        for (key, value) in dictionary {
                            if key as! String == "access_token" {
                                newAccessToken = value as? String
                            }
                            if key as! String == "refresh_token" {
                                newRefreshToken = value as? String
                            }
                        }

                        guard newAccessToken != nil && newRefreshToken != nil else {
                            completion(.failure(.general))
                            return
                        }

                        print("Renewed session tokens.")

                        do {
                            try Locksmith.updateData(data: [MySession.accessTokenKeychainKey: newAccessToken!, MySession.refreshTokenKeychainKey: newRefreshToken!],
                                                     forUserAccount: MySession.myKeychainAccount)
                        }
                        catch {
                            completion(.failure(.general))
                        }

                        completion(.success(newAccessToken!))

                    case let .failure(error):
                        if error == MyError.authenticationFailure {
                            print(“Session refresh failed due to authentication error; invalidating session.")
                            self.invalidate()
                        }

                        completion(.failure(error))
                    }

                }

            case let .failure(error):
                completion(.failure(error))
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app is likely being launched in the background while the device is locked (for app refresh or other background mode you've configured). Protected data (including Keychain) is not necessarily available at that time. You can check `UIApplication.isProtectedDataAvailable` to check if it's available, and you can reduce the protection of the item to `kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlock` in order to have background access more reliably (though not 100% promised, even in that mode). Locksmith calls this `AfterFirstUnlock`.

Comment: This gives me a direction! Thanks Rob! I will add some logs and see if this is the actual case.

Comment: Rob: I have enabled activity logging to see what exactly is going on, but am almost sure that the explanation you provided is the actual cause. I see that Locksmith doesn't directly give an option to modify the access level. How do I modify it to "AfterFirstUnlock" in that case?

Comment: I don't know anything about Locksmith, but the tool is Keychain command is `SecItemUpdate` (or you can set it during `SecItemAdd`). For some examples see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42101958/how-do-you-set-the-keychains-access-to-be-ksecattraccessibleafterfirstunlock-in/42184009#42184009 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26332351/secitemupdate-keeps-returning-errsecparam-and-i-cant-figure-out-why

Comment: the issue is exactly what you mentioned in your answer Rob. And then, I changed the security access level from `whenUnlocked` to `afterFirstUnlock`. But the issue is still reproducible. Not sure where the problem is.

Comment: I may have led you wrong with mentioning SecItemUpdate. That won't change meta-data. You need to remove the item and re-add it (SecItemAdd).